# Customise insert/edit window in tiny mce editor

Tags: css, hyperlink, tinymce

This is the insert/edit link window on iPhone:

[image]

On iPad:

[image]

As you can see, the list of topics touches the search box. On opera it is worse and overlaps the search box:

[image: Opera]

How can I fix this and set the window text as blag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this CSS seems to work for me:

```
/* TinyMCE Link Box */
div#link-selector {
    color: black !important;
}

/* TinyMCE Link Search Box */
div#most-recent-results.query-results {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Example in Opera:

[image: Opera]

The search list is no longer overlapping the search edit box.